# i have an mvc application , in that data is not getting saved in db while clicking on save button in chrome or edge but it is working fine in IE

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, model-view-controller, microsoft-edge

> adding finalpartiallysave function where uncaught is coming in console
> same code is working in IE but in chrome, edge or firefox it is not working , data is not gettinenter code hereg saved in  DB
> please let me know if anything is needed i am stuck in it.
> attaching below function for refrences
> i tried to check about ajax and aysnc  but it is not working

```
function FinalPartiallySave() {

            var separator = ";";
            var strPartiallyRows = "";

            var Error = "";
           

            var strSchemesRows = "";

            // New Schemes
            jQuery(".damage_new_scheme_row").each(function () {
                var SchemeName = $(this).find('.new_scheme_name').val();
                var Scheme = $(this).attr('scheme_id');
                var SchemeDenomination = $(this).find('.new_scheme_denomination').val();
                var SchemeQty = $(this).find('.new_scheme_qty').val();
                var Mapid = $(this).attr("mapid");


                Scheme = (Scheme == undefined) ? "" : Scheme;
                SchemeDenomination = (SchemeDenomination == undefined) ? "" : SchemeDenomination;
                SchemeQty = (SchemeQty == undefined) ? "" : SchemeQty;
                Mapid = (Mapid == undefined) ? "" : Mapid;

                if (SchemeQty == "0" || SchemeQty == "") {
                    Error += "Please enter Valid Qty for " + SchemeName + " Scheme \n";
                }
                else {
                    strSchemesRows = strSchemesRows +
                                    "" + separator +
                                    "" + separator +
                                    "" + separator +
                                    SchemeDenomination + separator +
                                    SchemeQty + separator +
                                    Mapid + separator +
                                    Scheme + ",";
                }
            });




            var dScheme = "";
            var ddl = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_dc1_ddlscheme");
            for (var index = 0; index < ddl.all.length; index++) {
                if (ddl.all[index].selected) {
                    dScheme = ddl.all[index].text;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var dSchemeId = jQuery('#hd_scheme_id').val();

            var dSchemeDenomination = jQuery(".damage_new_scheme_row1").find('.new_scheme_denomination').val();
            var dSchemeQty = jQuery(".damage_new_scheme_row1").find('.new_scheme_qty').val();
            var dMapid = "0";

            dScheme = (dScheme == undefined) ? "Select" : dScheme;
            dSchemeDenomination = (dSchemeDenomination == undefined) ? "" : dSchemeDenomination;
            dSchemeQty = (dSchemeQty == undefined) ? "" : dSchemeQty;
            dMapid = (dMapid == undefined) ? "" : dMapid;

            if (dScheme == "Select" && (dSchemeDenomination != "0" || dSchemeQty != "")) {
                Error += "Please enter New Scheme Name\n";
            }
            if (dSchemeId == "-1" && (dSchemeDenomination != "0" || dSchemeQty != "")) {
                Error += "Please enter Valid New Scheme Name\n";
            }
            if (dSchemeDenomination == "0" && (dScheme != "Select" || dSchemeQty != "")) {
                Error += "Please select Coupon Type for " + dScheme + " Scheme\n";
            }
            if (dSchemeQty == "" && (dScheme != "Select" || dSchemeDenomination != "0")) {
                Error += "Please enter Qty for " + dScheme + " Scheme\n";
            }
            if (dSchemeQty == "0" && (dScheme != "Select" || dSchemeDenomination != "0" || dSchemeQty == "")) {
                Error += "Please enter Valid Qty for " + dScheme + " Scheme\n";
            }


            if (dScheme != "Select" && dSchemeDenomination != "0") {
                if (!FindDuplicateNewSchemeRows(dScheme, dSchemeDenomination)) {

                    strSchemesRows = strSchemesRows +
                                        "" + separator +
                                        "" + separator +
                                        "" + separator +
                                        dSchemeDenomination + separator +
                                        dSchemeQty + separator +
                                        dMapid + separator +
                                        dSchemeId + ",";
                }
                else {
                    Error += "Duplicate New Schemes Damage\n";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Judge from your second code, it looks more like `Web Forms` instead of MVC. Also, I cannot reproduce this issue since I don't have your custom classes/functions. I also need, if any, error messages in the console. It can help narrow down the scope.

Comment: getting below on console error       --FinalPartiallySave @ CouponVerification.a…308253&Stage=6:4752
--onclick @ CouponVerification.a…308253&Stage=6:4396  added code for FinalPartiallySave

Comment: Is this error message from Visual Studio console? Actually, I mean the Edge/Chrome devtools console. If the button click does not work, you should see the error message in that console when you click the save button.

Comment: in console it is showing uncaught function, i tried to debug it is not showing any error only it is failing at  for (var index = 0; index < ddl.all.length; index++)  and showing cross sign at length and index++. but not displaying any error message . ANd same is working in IE

Answer (score 0):

After checking your code, I've found something unusual. It may have something to do with the incompatibility issue.

```
    var ddl = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_dc1_ddlscheme");
    for (var index = 0; index < ddl.all.length; index++) {
        if (ddl.all[index].selected) {
            dScheme = ddl.all[index].text;
            break;
        }
    }
```

We now have `document.getElementById('id').all`, which is `undefined`. Also, `all` is deprecated now, so I suggest trying `querySelectorAll` instead.